# Trying to set image in the PresentViewController with ImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive got a storyboard with 2 ViewControllers, the first ViewController got a button to pick a photo from the photo album. The second ViewController has a ImageView.
the outcome is a black screen.

This is the delegate method:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    UIImage * selectedIMG = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    VCImageEditingViewController *ieVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCImageEditingViewController"];
    ieVC.selectedIMG = selectedIMG;
    [self presentViewController: ieVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

In the VCImageEditingViewController.m:

```
    -(void)loadView
{
    if (self.selectedIMG) {
       self.imageDisplayed.image = self.selectedIMG;
    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hat.jpg"];
        self.imageDisplayed.image = image;
    }
}
```

Even when i change the if statement to show the "hat" photo in both cases it shows me a black screen, so i'm pretty sure its got to do with the image picker.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In loadView, if(self.selectedIMG) [self.imageView setImage:self.selectedIMG];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- You are using `loadView` when you should be using `viewDidLoad` and calling `[super viewDidLoad]`
- The line: `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.imageDisplayed];` doesn't display the image on the image view, it should be: `self.imageDisplayed.image = self.selectedIMG;`

Comment: Sorry, the original code was "self.imageDisplayed.image = self.selectedIMG;""

Comment: Then just the viewDidLoad part, or even viewWillAppear will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are overriding loadView, for a controller you set up in the storyboard.

The docs say for loadView:

*If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.
....*

*If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad method.*

Try to override `-(void) viewDidLoad` instead, and set the image for the ImageView (assuming that you have set up `self.imageDisplay` up as a View Controller's view's subview) there.